# How to omit reading of first line using sed , when a variable is used?

Tags: bash, sed

I want to read datas based on timestamp. Check the first line of the input file, if it matches the $timestamp, remove the lines that is above the obtained maximum timestamp. I used the below command but throws error in my sed command which I wrote for deleting lines obtained before $timestamp. Where am I wrong?

```
timestamp=`(exec mysql db -u xxx -pxxx -s -N -e "select max(time) from table;")`

sed -e '1/"$timestamp"/d' /home/xx/xx
```

Comment: your description is not easy to understand, can you make before / after examples so that we know what do you really want to do.

Comment: The first immediately obvious problem is that you're using single quotes, so the shell variable will not be expanded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you want to do is, check the first line of the input file, if it matches the `$timestamp`, remove the line, if it doesn't match, do nothing on the file.

Your sed codes are wrong, please read some tutorial. This line should work:

```
sed "1{/$timestamp/d}" /home/whatever
```

Comment: The syntax worked, Thank You. But I need lines that came after the $timestamp but this command gives me lines that came before the $timestamp.

Comment: istn't the line first line in your file? I don't understand what do you mean. again, paste input/output examples.

Comment: Actually I am sending log files to mysql based on timestamp. So files once send need to be omitted the next time when I send. That is my aim.